# MVC4: How to get action's parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I create a system in MVC4 that logs all user actions.
How can I get the action's parameter from inside the controller.

I know that Controller and ApiController belong to different namespaces, so does anyone know of a way for both controller types?